# Android app doesn't like transparent profile images

Tags: bug, android-app, profile-picture

App version: 1.0.52

My profile image should be

[image]

But it is displaying with a black background on the app.

[image]

Comment: For the starter, I couldn't repro this on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app 1.0.82 (beta); your avatar is rendered correctly on the question box. However, seems there's a bug of Android on rendering GIF with transparency on Android 4.4 KitKat ~ 5.1 Lollipop ([AOSP Issue Tracker #81975](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81975), fixed on Android 6.0 Marshmallow). Could you mention your Android version and possibly, the device model? For workaround, convert your avatar to PNG.